# DB2 alias in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, db2

I have a couple DB2 tables, one for `users` and one for `newsletters` and I want to select using an alias in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT a.*, b.tech_id as user FROM users a  
JOIN newsletter b ON b.tech_id = a.newsletter_id
WHERE timestamp(user) < current_timestamp
```

This is radically simplified so I can see what's going on, but I am getting an error that makes me think that the `user` alias isn't getting passed correctly:

```
ERROR: An invalid datetime format was detected; that is, an 
invalid string representation or value was specified.
```

The `user.tech_id` is a string built from the `datetime` when the record was created, so it looks something like `20150210175040951186000000`. I've verified that I can execute a `timestamp(tech_id)` successfully-- so it can't be the format of the field causing the problem.

Any ideas?

More information:

There's multiple newsletters per user. I need to get the most recent newsletter (by the tech_id) and check if that was created in the past week. So the more complex version would be something like:

```
SELECT a.*, b.tech_id as user FROM users a  
JOIN newsletter b ON b.tech_id = a.newsletter_id
WHERE timestamp(max(user)) < current_timestamp
```

Is there a way to `JOIN` only on the most recent record?

Comment: in many dbms "user" is a reserved word and using it as a column alias is very likely to be a problem anyway. I would suggest not using "user" maybe "techuser"? anyway something other than "user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get most recent newsletter of user, consider ordering the join query, then select top record (in DB2 you would use [FETCH FIRST ONLY](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005280.html)):

```
SELECT a.*, b.tech_id as user 
  FROM users a  
INNER JOIN newsletter b ON b.tech_id = a.newsletter_id
ORDER BY b.tech_id
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Alternatively, you can use a subquery in `WHERE` clause that aggregates the max user:

```
SELECT a.*, b.tech_id as user 
  FROM users a  
WHERE b.tech_id IN (
  SELECT Max(n.tech_id) as maxUser
  FROM users u 
  INNER JOIN newsletter n ON n.tech_id = u.newsletter_id)
```

I left out the condition of `timestamp(user) < current_timestamp` as data stored in database will always be less than current time (i.e., now).

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution is different to the order of writing. The FROM & WHERE clauses are executed before the SELECT clause hence the alias does not exist when you are trying to use it.

You would have to "nest" part of the query so that the alias is defined before the where clause. Can be easier in many cases to not use the alias.

try

```
WHERE timestamp(b.tech_id) < current_timestamp
```

The generic "order of execution" of SQL clauses is

```
FROM
   JOINs (as part of the from clause)
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY
```

**Is there a way to JOIN only on the most recent record?**

A useful technique for this is using ROW_NUMBER() assuming your DB2 supports it, and would look something like this:

```
SELECT
      a.*
    , b.tech_id AS techuser
FROM users a
JOIN (
      SELECT
            *
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp(tech_id) DESC) AS RN
      FROM newsletter
) b
      ON b.tech_id = a.newsletter_id
      AND b.rn = 1
```

this would give you just one row from newsletter, and using the DESCending order gives you the "most recent" assuming timestamp(tech_id) works as described.

Comment: @Used_By_Already-- thanks! That's a great explanation. Would you mind taking a look at my edits and explaining how to deal with the more detailed scenario?

Comment: running just `SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY timestamp(tech_id) DESC) AS RN FROM PROSPECT_LINK` gives a generic error about a token missing, which is the same that happens when I run the whole thing.

Comment: `gives a generic error about a token missing` OK, unable to comment on an error without details of it. But I am unfamiliar with this: `timestamp(tech_id)` if you replaced that with any other column of the newsletter table to order by, does the query run OK? Point is I cannot debug only you can. e.g. Is it necessary to use timestamp(....)? could the query without using that function?